# Evaluate a certain integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am a beginner with Mathematica, and I would like to know if it is possible to calculate this kind of integral:

$$
\int\limits_0^{0.8}\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi z}{1.6} \right)\int\limits_z^{\infty}\frac{e^{-3.367u}}{u^2}du\ dz
$$

Comment: I see two integrals signs, but only one `d something` at the end. Is this mathematically even valid?

Comment: already corrected, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` yet?

Answer (score 5):

You can evaluate it like this, but it blows up at z=0

First evaluate the inner integral on its own

```
 int1=Assuming[z>= 0,Integrate[  Exp[-3367/1000 u]/u^2,{u,z,Infinity}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see that it has to be for `z>0` now evaluate the complete integral

```
 Integrate[ Cos[ Pi z/(16/10)]^2* int1 ,{z,0,8/10},PrincipalValue->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]